# Spring Integration flow for consuming gmail messages with file attachments, by example

Tags: gmail, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

Spring Integration 5.x here. I am trying to write an `IntegrationFlow` that:

1. Reads emails from a Gmail account. If the emails do not contain file attachments, they are ignored and simlpy marked as "Read". Otherwise...
2. For each email with attachments, and for each one of those attachments, I need the attachment to be in the `Message<?>` body (as a `byte[]` or similar) and I need to send the message off to a bean handler called `documentRegistrar`. My best attempt thus far is this:

```
@Configuration
public class GmailIntegrationConfiguration {

    private String emailHost;
    private String emailUsername;
    private String emailPassword;
    private DocumentRegistrar documentRegistrar;

    @Autowired
    public GmailIntegrationConfiguration(
            @Value("${email.host}") String emailHost,
            @Value("${email.username}") String emailUsername,
            @Value("${email.password}") String emailPassword,
            DocumentRegistrar documentRegistrar) {
        this.emailHost = emailHost;
        this.emailUsername = emailUsername;
        this.emailPassword = emailPassword;
        this.awsAccessKey = awsAccessKey;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow gmailIntegrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(emailAdapterSpec ->
            Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imap://imapuser:pw@localhost:993/INBOX")
                    .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"))
                    .autoCloseFolder(false))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                .handle(documentRegistrar)
            .get();
    }

}
```

The code for `Mail.imapInboundAdapter` and `createImapAdapterSpec` is just what I was able to *Frankenstein* together using the Spring Integration docs and a few Google searches, but they are both fraught with compiler errors.

Can anyone help nudge me over the finish line with a concrete working example here? Specifically the `Mail.imapInboundAdapter` does not have `port`, `user` `password`, etc. builder methods on it, so how would I configure all of those? And the file attachements filter is definitely wrong as Spring does not appear to have a `MimeBodyPart` type defined (at all). Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what drove you to that configuration style, since it is clear from the  `Mail.imapInboundAdapter()` API that there is no those props.
There is only this:

```
public static ImapMailInboundChannelAdapterSpec imapInboundAdapter(String url) {
```

So, you need to build an URL from those your parts.

Something in style with this sample:

Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imap://imapuser:pw@localhost:993/INBOX")

And yes, folder need to be present as a part of the IMAP URL.

See `.autoCloseFolder(false)` option and its Javadocs for mutlipart mail to be parsed downstream:

```
/**
 * Configure a {@code boolean} flag to close the folder automatically after a fetch (default) or
 * populate an additional {@link IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor#CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE} message header instead.
 * It is the downstream flow's responsibility to obtain this header and call its {@code close()} whenever
 * it is necessary.
 * <p> Keeping the folder open is useful in cases where communication with the server is needed
 * when parsing multipart content of the email with attachments.
 * <p> The {@link #setSimpleContent(boolean)} and {@link #setHeaderMapper(HeaderMapper)} options are not
 * affected by this flag.
 * @param autoCloseFolder {@code false} do not close the folder automatically after a fetch.
 * @since 5.2
 */
public void setAutoCloseFolder(boolean autoCloseFolder) {
```

If you don't provide a `HeaderMapper`, then with `.autoCloseFolder(false)`, the whole `MimeMessage` is provided in the payload. The channel adapter does not determine if there are some attachments in the mail message or not. More over it seems Gmail always produce mutilpart message even if there is just one simple part in the body.

You probably need to push the parsing and filtering logic down to your `documentRegistrar` and don't forget to close the folder from time to time: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan (+1) just 2 quick followup questions regarding your answer if you don't mind: **(1)** I'm now getting the following compiler error on `.from(...)`: "_Ambiguous method call. Both from (Publisher<? extends Message<?>>) in IntegrationFlows and from (IntegrationFlow) in IntegrationFlows match_", any idea what the fix is there? And **(2)** Any reason to just always keep the folder open, if the intention is to read emails sent 24/7/365? And if there is, what's the recommended approach for opening/closing folders every so often? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure in the compiler error, see if upgrading to Java 17 helps you. We need folder to be opened for processing those attachments. You indeed can close when you done with the message. However then you need to fetch only one. On the other hand the `AbstractMailReceiver` closes the folder automatically when no new messages to produce, even if we turn on that option to keep it opened.

Comment: In that case (with the `AbstractMailReceiver`) how would I ever re-open the folder, when I go to do a fetch again? It sounds like I need to schedule this flow to poll the SMTP every minute or so maybe? Ideally it would just continuous read the inbox folder 24/7.

Comment: The channel adapter does reopen the folder automatically on the next poll. Not sure why is the question. It is closed and reopened by default anyway.